# Getting error "WMI: Not Found" on a Windows 2003 Server

Tags: windows-server-2003, wmi

I'm getting the following error whenever I try to view the dependencies for any service on our Windows 2003 Enterprise Server:

```
WMI: Not Found
```

So three questions pop into my head at this point:

1. Obviously, what can I do to fix this? Hopefully the answer is not a re-pave.
2. Is it actually possible that WMI is not installed? I didn't set this machine up so I'm not sure what the other person did.
3. Could the WMI repository be corrupt?

So, how can I fix this? How can I tell if WMI was just not installed or if the WMI Repository is corrupt?

Answer (score 1):

The following script can be run to rebuild a corrupt WMI
(Source: [Duncan McAlynn, 2004-11-22, How Do I Rebuilt a Corrupt WMI Repository?](http://msmvps.com/blogs/lduncan/pages/20217.aspx)) <sub>(Dead link. Archived version [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20130828192038/https://msmvps.com/blogs/lduncan/pages/20217.aspx).)</sub>

```
net stop winmgmt
c: 
cd %systemroot%\system32\wbem 
rd /S /Q repository 


regsvr32 /s %systemroot%\system32\scecli.dll 
regsvr32 /s %systemroot%\system32\userenv.dll 


mofcomp cimwin32.mof 
mofcomp cimwin32.mfl 
mofcomp rsop.mof 
mofcomp rsop.mfl 
for /f %%s in ('dir /b /s *.dll') do regsvr32 /s %%s 
for /f %%s in ('dir /b *.mof') do mofcomp %%s 
for /f %%s in ('dir /b *.mfl') do mofcomp %%s 
echo DONE reboot 
pause
```

Comment: The Microsoft "AskPerf" blog has a similar but more in depth post. And they warn that: *"If you suspect WMI or repository corruption, rebuilding repository is the last thing you should do."* (They suggest tryping WmiDiag.exe and some other things first.) -> [CC Hameed, 2009-04-13, Microsoft TechNet "AskPerf" blog, "WMI: Rebuilding the WMI Repository"](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askperf/2009/04/13/wmi-rebuilding-the-wmi-repository/) (Archived [here](https://archive.is/xBcY8).)

Answer (score 0):

Check out the folder `%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem\Repository\FS` -- this is where your WMI repository is stored. If there are files in there, it means it is installed, but probably corrupt.

Delete everything in `%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem\Repository` then reboot to fix the problem.

Alternatively, you could try Microsoft's [WMI Diagnosis Utility](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=d7ba3cd6-18d1-4d05-b11e-4c64192ae97d&displaylang=en) to diagnose WMI.

Comment: Actually, deleting the repository is the last thing to do, especially in a production environment, because it is likely to create further problems (if I remember correctly the documentation that comes with WMIDiag.vbs - your second link - also suggests this) I even remember a webcast by Alain Lissoir about WMI troubleshooting that begins by 'Please do not delete the repository' - I will try to find it and post the link.

Comment: Here is the webcast I was talking about:

http://www.microsoft.com/events/series/detail/webcastdetails.aspx?seriesid=6&webcastid=1470